# Lab color sphere as Cycles Material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color

Is there any possibility to create a Cycles Material of a 3D-gradient, to get a Lab color sphere like this?:

[image: Lab color sphere]

So if I place different objects of the same Material they get the color depending on where they are placed? I already got a regular gradient with this effect.

[image: Regular gradient]

But how can I combine it with two other gradients? (blue to yellow from front to back and white to black from top to bottom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as I understand you want your object green to red from left to right, and blue to yellow from front to back. Using the sperate XYZ node you can achieve this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Combined with mapping I got nearly the effect i wanted.
[image]
But I also want the gradient from top to bottom to be from white to black. 
I added a ColorRamp to Z from Separate XYZ but it only gets brighter to the top. How do i get it darker to the bottom? And i also want the middle to be grey and the farther away an object from the center is placed, the more saturation it gets. So that the 3D-space behaves from top view like the color wheel.

[image: color wheel]

Comment: I think at this point the simplest solution would be to google search for a color wheel texture, then UV unwrap the object from top orthogonal view and apply that texture to it.

Comment: Also, to get it darker at the bottom, you can connect the color ramp node to the Fac. of the last mix shader, and leave the diffuse with a black color as you would do normally. This way it won't lighten te top part, and you will be able to adjust where the blackness starts, as well as it's intensity using the colorramp.

Comment: This should be an [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/82405/edit) to the original question since it adds to the question, but doesn't solve it.