# How do I apply color with Cycles Material Nodes with No UV?

Tags: color

After many attempts I can't figure out how to make the ends of the lemon green.
Here's my latest attempt. I've tried mapping, etc.

[image]

Comment: Try this: do an UV unwrap of the lemon, then add a texture coordinate node, and plug it into the gradient texture node you already have using UV. Then in UV/imagee ditor rotate the uv map (if necessary)

Comment: was hoping I could accomplish this without UV. May not be possible, dunno.

Comment: I think it's either that or using XYZ, see my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82405/lab-color-sphere-as-cycles-material/82411#82411

Comment: Is this an interesting node experiment or is there some larger purpose?  Why not use a quick texture paint?

Comment: I don't know how to use texture paint. I was following a Sardi Pax tut on using procedural textures. Some of us are still learning.

Answer (score 1):

**Nodes using Generated Coordinates**

**No UV**

[image]

Nodes Use Generated X Coordinates.  Image above.    Cleanup Pending. We think these are better attached to vertices and survive rotation as the image shows a translated and rotated lemon. See axis orientation.  Please test and confirm.  Artistry not considered.

Please improve these nodes.

**Deprecated Nodes of Lemon Quality abusing the X position of fragment.**

[image]

Cycles Render.  Less Green.  X Coordinate used. Object Centered at Origin.  Image Above.  Keeping some old nodes until cleanup.

[image]

More Green.  Nodes showing use of X Coordinate.  Left and Right value made equal via Absolute Value Node.

The Multiplication node controls the spread.  Its value is keyframed.

Do not eat lemons like this.

Comment: My lemon mesh is not aligned with the xyz coords. It's rotated on the z axis. No reason for that, it just was left that way after modeling. I guess that's why it's showing a "diagonal" yellow/green? Hey, I'm trying.

Comment: @NeverGiveUp I do not think I can interpret your results without an investigation.  So I cannot agree or disagree.

Comment: @NeverGiveUp  Do you understand at least 50% of the nodes above?